# How to increment or decrement height of a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my attempt to decrement by 28:

```
var addItemForm = $('.add-item-form');
var h = addItemForm.height()-28;
var h = toString(h);
addItemForm.height(h);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your height is in pixels, you can just write:

```
​$(".add-item-form").height("-=28");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

... and similarly to increment:

```
$(".add-item-form").height("+=28");
```

Check out the documentation for [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height) for more information.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VDcLs/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a script error for duplicate declaration of `var h`. try below,

```
var addItemForm = $('.add-item-form');
var h = addItemForm.height()-28;
var h1 = toString(h); //<-- This returns a valid integer as a number/string.
addItemForm.height(h1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var h = addItemForm.height("-=28");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var addItemForm = $('.add-item-form');
var h = addItemForm.height()-28;
addItemForm.height(h);
```